# Passing Class as parameter for use with typeof()

Tags: c#

I have a delegate function:

```
myDelegate md = cls => String.Format("blahblah: {0}", typeof(cls).FullName));
```

I want to pass a `Class` there as parameter `cls`, which will be used in `typeof()`.

Example use:

```
md(System.String); // => blahblah: System.string
```

What type to define for input parameter `cls`, to be able passing any `Class` into my function?

Comment: YOu can pass `Type cls`

Comment: If you're willing to shift to passing the *type*, this is quite straightforward - but the `typeof` will have to be used at the call site rather than within the method. Otherwise, I think you're stuck.

Comment: `typeof(cls)` could be replaced by `cls.GetType()` which would make your code compile and print the the type of `cls` as you seem to want. I don't really understand what exactly you are trying to achieve though, so not sure if that fits your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are looking for is `Type`.

Use it like this:

```
myDelegate md = cls => String.Format("blahblah: {0}", cls.FullName));
md(typeof(System.String));
```

You can also use generics to get similar results

```
public static string TypePrinter<T>()
{
    return String.Format("blahblah: {0}", typeof(T).FullName));
}
TypePrinter<System.String>();
```

Comment: First solution works, but the seconds complaints something like `cannot use type in context`

Comment: My bad, I wrote it without compiling and made a mistake. Updated the answer and converted to C# 5.

Comment: Both version works now. Damn these strongly typed languages, Sometimes it demands very complicated construct to achieve relatively simple task. At least I've learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, but having a compiler tell you "shit won't work" is worth a lot in bigger projects. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something similar to this-

```
Func<Type,string> fn = t => string.Format("blah from - {0}",t.FullName);
Console.WriteLine(fn(typeof(Int32))); //blah from - System.Int32
```

Comment: [`Func<T, TResult> Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) is exactly what I was looking for. I'm just unable to pass `Class` directly, I have to pass `Type` as a result of `typeof()` call, which is less DRY, but affordable.